# Bootstrap 4.1.1 not working on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I already ran bundle install, bundle update and everything, but my app isn't changing anything using bootstrap code.

I included it on my Gemfile exactly like this:

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
```

My layout file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Title</title>


 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data- 
 turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 
 'reload' %>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
 shrink-to-fit=no">
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="container">
 <%= yield %>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

My application.scss file:

```
@import 'bootstrap'
```

Comment: Did you import it in application.scss file? `@import "bootstrap";`

Comment: Yes I did, into my stylesheets folder.

Comment: Please upload your `layout` file and `application.scss` file content. Try to restart the server.

Comment: Done. And yes, I've tried restarting my server too.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to REPLACE and existing file, which is "application.css" to an .scss extention. I was having BOTH css and scss in the same folder.

Problem solved!